# How can I change the monospace font in desktop Slack?

Tags: slack

I know about the `/slackfont` command to change the general UI/message font; I would like a way to select a different font for `code` spans and blocks/snippets in the Slack desktop app (on Linux in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option in the Slack preferences that I can see to change fonts at all, and changing the font via `/slackfont` does only change the main channel font without changing the code blocks here as well.

It appears you're out of luck for the moment, but you could make a feature request to the Slack team at https://slack.com/help .